# Custom Queries with Java JPA returning "NULL"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I'm currently having some first time experience with JAVA SpringBoot for a university project, in which we are using a H2 in-mem database for storage. For statistics i want to use a custom query to get data - which works perfectly fine. However when getting to work with the returned data i have quite the issues and need help.

My query returns 4 columns (name, avgTasteRating,avgDesignRating,avgPriceRating). To parse the information within Java i built a custom Entity (WineDTO) consisting of the same columns. However only the name is parsed - the rest is casted as "null" for some reason..

Does anyone have any ideas for possible errors or fixes? Greatly appreciated! Thanks you so much!!!

WineRepository.java

```
    @Query(value =
        "SELECT w.NAME, AVG(r.taste_rating) AS avgTasteRating, AVG(r.design_rating) AS avgDesignRating,AVG(r.price_rating) AS avgPriceRating" +
                "            FROM WINE w JOIN RATING r ON w.ID = r.wine_id" +
                "            GROUP BY w.ID, w.NAME" +
                "            ORDER BY avgTasteRating DESC", nativeQuery = true)
List<WineDTO> findWinesWithAverageRatings();
```

WineDTO.java

```
@Entity
public class WineDTO {

private String name;
private String avgTasteRating;
private String avgDesignRating;
private String avgPriceRating;
@Id
private Long id;

// constructer, set and get to follow
```

Comment: data type of aggregate function is not `String`, can you try `Double` as datatype for `avgTasteRating`, `avgDesignRating ` and `avgPriceRating`? and generally it is recommended to use **Projections** in this case, please check here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/projections.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion! Using Double returned "null" as well unfortunately. Building a ProjectionInterface however solved my issue. Greatly appreciated

Comment: I think the problem may be that you are mixing `jpql` (`..FROM WINE w..`) but at the same time saying `nativeQuery = true`, which implies writing a query in pure sql

Comment: @Florian I'm pleased that it resolved the issue for you. I elaborated on the same solution in my response, anticipating it might be helpful for someone facing a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Spring Data JPA Projection Interface instead of an Entity, you need to define a projection interface that includes the fields you want to select. Here's an example:

**Projection Interface:**

```java
public interface WineDTO {

    String getName();
    Double getAvgTasteRating();
    Double getAvgDesignRating();
    Double getAvgPriceRating();
    Long getId();
}
```

In this interface, the method names should match the names of the fields you are selecting in your query.

**JPA Repository:**

```java
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import java.util.List;

public interface WineRepository extends JpaRepository<Wine, Long> {

    @Query(value =
            "SELECT w.NAME, AVG(r.taste_rating) AS avgTasteRating, AVG(r.design_rating) AS avgDesignRating, AVG(r.price_rating) AS avgPriceRating" +
                    " FROM WINE w JOIN RATING r ON w.ID = r.wine_id" +
                    " GROUP BY w.ID, w.NAME" +
                    " ORDER BY avgTasteRating DESC", nativeQuery = true)
    List<WineDTO> findWinesWithAverageRatings();
}
```

Ensure that the method in the repository returns a List of the defined projection interface (`WineDTO` in this case).

Remember that Spring Data JPA will map the results of the native query to the fields in your projection interface based on their names, so the names in the interface should match the aliases in your native query.

If you want to read more on Spring Data JPA Projections, check the official doc here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/projections.html